# How do I access elements in multi dimension array/list in Dart

Tags: arrays, dart

I am beginner in Dart. 
Following is an array and I need to access a specific element

`'text': 'Rabbit'`and `'score': 3`

I tried the below:

```
_questions[1]['answers'][0]['text']['score']
```

This doesn't work.

```
var _questions = [
{
  'question': 'What is your color?',
  'answers': [
    {'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
    {'text': 'Red', 'score': 5},
    {'text': 'Green', 'score': 3},
    {'text': 'White', 'score': 1},
  ],
},
{
  'question': 'What is your animal?',
  'answers': [
    {'text': 'Rabbit', 'score': 3},
    {'text': 'Snake', 'score': 11},
    {'text': 'Elephant', 'score': 5},
    {'text': 'Lion', 'score': 9},
  ],
},
];
```

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I don't know Dart!) I've played a bit with the code using [dartpad.dartlang.org](http://dartpad.dartlang.org):

Cast the answer object as `List`:

```
var answers = (_questions[1]['answers'] as List);
```

And then you can the first object data as:

```
answers[0]['text']
answers[0]['score']
```

Comment: This doesn't work. 
It gives the error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object'.

Comment: Thanks Luis. This works... so it means the child cannot be accessed directly.

Comment: Great. May be it can be accessed but I don’t know enough Dart to be sure about it. Please remember to accept the answer.